# NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Llevo varias horas buscando la solucion a este error. Ya intente con la indentacion, pero no hay caso. Es algo basico lo que estoy viendo, pero si no resuelvo este error no puedo continuar con el tutorial.

NOTA : main() esta indentado debajo de **NAME**

```
class Fraccion :
    
    num = 1
    den = 2



    def __init__(self):
        print(self.num)

    def imprime (self):
        print(self.num,"/",self.den)

    
    def main(self):

        a= Fraccion()


 if __ name __ == "__main __":  
       main()
```

Comment: `main()` es un método de la clase `Fraccion`, no puedes llamarlo sin ser desde dicha clase. Deberás crear un nuevo objeto de clase `Fraccion` y usarlo para llamar a `main()` -> `fr = Fraccion()` y luego podrás llamar a main-> `fr.main()`. Te recomiendo que *repases* el concepto de programación orientada a objetos en python :)

Comment: Creo que lo que ocurre es que has metido `main()` como método de la clase `Fraccion`,  cuando en realidad lo que pretendes es que sea un método "independiente" (pues veo que dentro de él se instancia esa misma clase). Es decir, el código de `main` no debe estar indentado dentro de `Fraccion`. Su `def` debe estar a la misma altura que `class` o que el `if`.

Comment: Intente hacerlo de esa manera pero recibo "name fr Is not a defined"

Comment: Acabo de indentarlo debajo de class e if y recibo ( main() missing 1 required positional al argument: "self") ingreso main(self) y recibo " self Is not defined"

Comment: El parámetro `self` se declara en los métodos de un objeto. Si conviertes `main()` en una función "normal" (fuera del objeto), tienes que quitarle ese parámetro y dejar simplemente `def main():`

Comment: Otro error que veo es que has puesto espacios alrededor de los signos `__`, que no deben estar. El símbolo se llama `__name__` y se debe comparar con `"__main__"` sin espacios.

Answer (score 0):

La función `main` no es parte de la clase `Fraccion`; tiene que ser declarada fuera de la clase.

La función `main` no es parte de una clase; no lleva argumento `self`.

```
class Fraccion:
    num = 1
    den = 2

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.num)

    def imprime(self):
        print(self.num, "/", self.den)


def main():
    a = Fraccion()


if __name__ == "__main __":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

El método main y la comprobación del entry point tienen que ir fuera de tu clase, como en el código que pongo debajo. La comprobacion de:

```
__name__ == __main__
```

Sirve para comprobar si nuestro script está siendo llamado desde la consola (haciendo algo como "python <fichero.py>").

Es en ese caso cuando queremos llamar nuestro metodo "main" que debe ser independiente de la clase, al menos en este ejemplo, puesto que lo que está haciendo es generar un objeto e interactuar con él.

```py
class Fraccion :   
    num = 1
    den = 2
    
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.num)
    
    def imprime (self):
        print(self.num,"/",self.den)
    
def main():
   a = Fraccion()
   a.imprime()
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

Comment: El código que propones tiene errores:     `main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'``

Comment: @CandidMoe Toda la razón, me basé en el codigo de la pregunta original que tenía el self, y no lo eliminé correctamente. Gracias :)